# Date Archives: Last 6 months

Tags: group, limit, archives

From the Creating an Archive Page for Entries article in the Craft docs. How could I limit it so that it grouped by month but limited things to 6 months?:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null) %}
{% for date, entries in allEntries | group("postDate|date('F Y')") %}
    <h2>{{ date }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% untested, but something like this should work using Twig's [date_modify](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date_modify.html) filter.

```
{% set startDate = now|date_modify("-6 months") %}

{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('blog').limit(null).postDate('>= ' ~ startDate) %}

{% for date, entries in allEntries | group("postDate|date('F Y')") %}
    <h2>{{ date }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Instead of `.postDate()` could this also be performed on a custom date/time field (in this case called `startDate`). I'm having trouble getting it to work: `.startDate('>= ' ~ range)`

Comment: Scratch that, I've managed to get it working now. Thanks Brad! :)

Comment: No worries! @Ian